# Tomcat 7.30 проблема с JDBC

Tags: jdbc, tomcat

Всем привет.
Есть сервлет,в котором я пытаюсь подключиться к БД.Вот код.

```
try { this.getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass("org.postgresql.Driver");}
         catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

try {
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432", "postgres","923506");
} catch (SQLException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

Выдает ошибку

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432

Небольшая предыстория и описание текущих настроек.

- Связка нынешней версии бд и jdbc драйвера работает на обычных(не web приложениях).
- Jar файл jdbc драйвера лежит в %CATALINA_HOME%/lib . В проекте этот файл указан в этой директории(до этого он лежал вообще в другом месте и ошибка возникала еще на моменте загрузки класса,тут же ошибка выдается на моменте подключения к БД).

Внимане, вопрос:
Что тут не так?

Comment: Так,уточнее.
Зашел http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html
и скачал 8.3-607 JDBC 2EE
поюзал,все так же

Comment: Добавочка: нашел tomcat - jdbc драйвер в либах в %CATALINA_HOME%
Та же проблема)

Comment: Проблема еще актуальна ? :)
Ваш код не видит драйвер, то есть
    loadClass("org.postgresql.Driver")
не срабатывает, в основном это из-за того что jar файл не добавлен в classpath проекта

Comment: Актуальна) решил таким образом,сделал отдельный файл под работу с БД, не слишком костыльный метод,поэтому я не стал рыться,почему напряму их сервлета не коннектило:) Кстати,вроде бы все добавлял.В ошибке той говорится,что ему эти дрова не нравятся

Answer (score 1):

Похоже на то, что ему не нравится как написан `connection` :

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432", "postgres","923506");
```

В описании драйвера указаны такие вариации:

- jdbc:postgresql:database
- jdbc:postgresql://host/database
- jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database

Попробуйте так :

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/DataBaseName", "postgres","923506");
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно конечно "в лобовую" как вы делаете, а можно и поизящнее: через JNDI DataSource в конфигурации Tomcat.

Это более системное, более безопасное и более правильное решение и про между прочим при таком способе вы сразу же еще паровозиком получите JDBC [connection pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool)

[Пример организации коннекта к Postgres](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Configuring+a+PostgreSQL+Datasource+in+Apache+Tomcat)

Ну если хотите по прежнему "в лобовую", то рецепт решения известен и уже [описан](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/175441/jdbc-glassfish-connection-pool)