# glassfish connection pool

Tags: glassfish, jdbc

Есть сервер glassfish, нужно настроить connection pool, ввел все настройки по [мануалу от оракла](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/820-4335/ablih/index.html), но в итоге у меня при проверке коннекта с админ панели glassfish выдает ошибку:

```
Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for : com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDataSource
```

погуглив я выяснил что она возникает из-за отсутствия файла по адресу :

> as-install/domains/domain_name/lib/ext

у меня там лежат две библиотеки, проверенные на работоспособность в условиях без сервера

- ОС: Ubuntu
- JDBC: jconn4.jar(JConnect), sajdbc4.jar
- GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 (build 5)
- Eclipse for java ee

**UPD:** закинул файлы так же в

- domain-dir/lib
- as-install/lib

**UPD2:** пинг заработал, вся проблема в том что у эклипса создаются папочки сервера отдельно и лежат они в дебрях :

> /home/user_home/soft/eclipse/plugins/oracle.eclipse.runtime.glassfish.build3122_1.0.0/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain_name/lib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Безразлично к серверу и драйверу или оси общее правило простое: класс должен лежать в пределах CLASSPATH JVM, в данном случае CLASSPATH JVM сервера.

Выведите в логи текущий CLASSPATH сервера, внимательно и вкурите и одним выверенным движением закиньте драйвер куда следует или модифицируйте CLASSPATH.

Comment: супер, а как теперь в коде использовать этот коннект к базе  ? :)

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос. Один пост=один вопрос.